# Java correct way convert/cast object to Double

Tags: java, casting, double

I need to convert Object o to Double. Is the correct way to convert it to String first?

Comment: What is the special type of your Object ? Is it actually a Double, or something else ?

Comment: What is Object? Is it an unknown class or a Double class that has been typed to an Object.

Comment: "I try to found, but all seems vague." - your question is too vague to get an obvious answer. please elaborate. What is 'Object o' and what's the intention?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't cast an object to a `Double` if the object is not a Double.

Check out the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

particularly note

`valueOf(double d);`

and

`valueOf(String s);`

Those methods give you a way of getting a `Double` instance from a String or double primitive.  (Also not the constructors; read the documentation to see how they work) The object you are trying to convert naturally has to give you something that can be transformed into a double.

Finally, keep in mind that `Double` instances are immutable -- once created you can't change them.

Answer (score 45):

```
new Double(object.toString());
```

But it seems weird to me that you're going from an Object to a Double. You should have a better idea what class of object you're starting with before attempting a conversion. You might have a bit of a code quality problem there.

Note that this is a conversion, not casting.

Comment: Double.valueOf(object.toString()) uses less memory

Comment: `Double(String)` and `Double(double)` constructors were deprecated in JDK 9 and [deprecated for removal in Java 16](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8249100)

Answer (score 22):

If your Object represents a number, eg, such as an Integer, you can cast it to a Number then call the doubleValue() method.

```
Double asDouble(Object o) {
    Double val = null;
    if (o instanceof Number) {
        val = ((Number) o).doubleValue();
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Works great when type of the object is a value type.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the instanceof operator to test to see if it is a double prior to casting. You can then safely cast it to a double. In addition you can test it against other known types (e.g. Integer) and then coerce them into a double manually if desired.

```
    Double d = null;
    if (obj instanceof Double) {
        d = (Double) obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java version prior to 1.7 you cannot cast object to primitive type

```
double d = (double) obj;
```

You can cast an Object to a Double just fine

```
Double d = (Double) obj;
```

Beware, it can throw a ClassCastException if your object isn't a Double

Comment: If the object can be double or integer so in that case what should we prefer ?

Comment: @Raj Saraogi : Both Double and Integer implement `java.lang.Number`.There's no equivalent for primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth mentioning -- if you were forced to use an older Java version prior to 1.5, and you are trying to use Collections, you won't be able to parameterize the collection with a type such as `Double`.

You'll have to manually "*box*" to the class `Double` when adding new items, and "*unbox*" to the primitive `double` by parsing and casting, doing something like this:

```
LinkedList lameOldList = new LinkedList();
lameOldList.add( new Double(1.2) );
lameOldList.add( new Double(3.4) );
lameOldList.add( new Double(5.6) );

double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0, len = lameOldList.size(); i < len; i++) {
  total += Double.valueOf( (Double)lameOldList.get(i) );
}
```

The old-school list will contain only type `Object` and so has to be cast to `Double`.

Also, you won't be able to iterate through the list with an enhanced-for-loop in early Java versions -- only with a for-loop.

Comment: Do you mean "prior to 1.5"? That's where generics and autoboxing were introduced. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Oops you are correct @AlexeyRomanov, I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked:

```
Object obj = 10;
String str = obj.toString(); 
double d = Double.valueOf(str).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all these methods for conversion ->

[image: obj2Double]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object myObj = 10.101;
    System.out.println("Cast to Double: "+((Double)myObj)+10.99);   //concates

    Double d1 = new Double(myObj.toString());
    System.out.println("new Object String - Cast to Double: "+(d1+10.99));  //works

    double d3 = (double) myObj;
    System.out.println("new Object - Cast to Double: "+(d3+10.99));     //works

    double d4 = Double.valueOf((Double)myObj);
    System.out.println("Double.valueOf(): "+(d4+10.99));        //works

    double d5 = ((Number) myObj).doubleValue();
    System.out.println("Cast to Number and call doubleValue(): "+(d5+10.99));       //works

    double d2= Double.parseDouble((String) myObj);
    System.out.println("Cast to String to cast to Double: "+(d2+10));       //works
}
```