# incompatible types on java objects

Tags: java

The compilier doesn't like assigning the element in the object to a variable type Double even though the element type is a Double.  What am I missing?

```
Object relWeights [][] = new Object[2][];
relWeights[0] = new String [] {
    "Venus", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"
};
relWeights[1] = new Double [] {
    0.78, 0.39, 2.65, 1.17, 1.05, 1.23
};
Double temp = relWeights[1][planetVisiting-1];
//compiler faults here with incompatible types

System.out.println("Your weight on " + relWeights[0][planetVisiting-1] + " is " + temp*weightOnEarth +"pounds");
}
```

Comment: You can't downcaste Object class object to Double. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503877/java-correct-way-convert-cast-object-to-double

Comment: 1. Include the actual error message. 2. `relweights[i][j]` is an `Object` as far as the compiler is concerned. You and I know it is a `Double`, but we're smarter than the compiler...

Comment: (@John3136 we maybe smarter, but we specified and implemented the Java language to not accept this anyways)

Comment: The line "Double temp =" needs a cast from Object to Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Object class as a type for any purpose, And then you want to convert your data to its own type. you need to cast that data like below :-

```
Object relWeights [][] = new Object[2][];
relWeights[0] = new String [] {"Venus", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
relWeights[1] = new Double [] {0.78, 0.39, 2.65, 1.17, 1.05, 1.23} ;
Double temp = (Double)relWeights[1][planetVisiting-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by @SSP described the problem quite well: The compiler only knows that your entries have the type `Object`. A typecast would be needed to tell the compiler that it is a `double`.

For the inferred use case, I would suggest using a `Map` and not an array. The base solution would be a little bit different though.

```
Map<String, Double> relWeights = new HashMap();
relWeights.put("Venus", 0.78);
relWeights.put("Mars", 0.39);
relWeights.put("Jupiter", 2.65);
relWeights.put("Saturn", 1.17);
relWeights.put("Uranus", 1.05);
relWeights.put("Neptune", 1.23);
```

A `Map` is a key value store. It assigns a value to each key. It is possible to say `relWeights.get("specific_key")` to get the value assigned to this key (in this example the `Double` assigned to the `String`).

```
String planet = "Jupiter";
double temp = relWeights.get(planet);
double weightOnEarth = 38.62;

System.out.println("Your weight on " + selectedPlanet + " is "
                   + temp*weightOnEarth + "pounds");
```

However, if you need the entry by number, it is important to mention that a `HashMap` is not ordered. In this case, you should use a `LinkedHashMap` and when you need to retrieve by position, convert the values into an `ArrayList`.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Double> relWeights = new LinkedHashMap<>();
relWeights.put("Venus", 0.78);
relWeights.put("Mars", 0.39);
relWeights.put("Jupiter", 2.65);
relWeights.put("Saturn", 1.17);
relWeights.put("Uranus", 1.05);
relWeights.put("Neptune", 1.23);

Double temp = (new ArrayList<Double>(relWeights.values())).get(position);
```

Comment: Perfectly you conceived the intended usage and appropriate data structure for that. With application. Remarks for the OP: `double temp = ...` is better as the primitive type `double` is for calculating and such. And `relWeights.entrySet()` delivers all key-value pairs of planet and relative weight.